# Almost split sequences inside a subcategory using QPA

Tags: representation-theory, gap, computer-algebra-systems

Let $A$ be a finite dimensional connected quiver algebra and $\Omega^n(A)$ the fullsubcategory of direct summands of $n$-th syzygy modules for some $n \geq 1$. For example in case $A$ is Gorenstein of Gorenstein dimension $g$, for $n=g$ this is the subcategory of Gorenstein projective $A$-modules.

> Question: Is there a way using the GAP-package QPA to obtain the left and right almost split sequences of a module $X \in \Omega^n(A)$ inside the subcategory $\Omega^n(A)$?

Answer (score 2):

As of now the only possibility would be if the subcategory $\Omega^n(A)$ is $^\perp T$ for some cotilting module $T$.  Then one can apply the command `AlmostSplitSequenceInPerpT( T, M )` to get the almost split sequence in $^\perp T$ ending in the module $M$.

We hope these comments are helpful.

The QPA-team.